# Perl: try::tiny to catch

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Parse;
use Try::Tiny;

my $etime = time;
my $stime = "";
try{
    my $dur = $etime - str2time($stime);
} catch {
    print "error: $!\n";
};
```

OUTPUT

```
Use of uninitialized value in subtraction (-) at perl_try.pl line 10.
```

Anyone know how to catch this?
This is not being caught in the catch block

Comment: It's not an error; it's just a warning.

Comment: how do you catch a warning. disable it from printing to stdout (preferably not removing "use warnings") im guessing

Comment: If Try::Tiny did catch an error, then it would be in `$_`, not `$!`. Also, warnings go to stderr, not stdout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try::Tiny doesn't do anything here because the message is just a warning, not an exception.

[`perldoc Date::Parse`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse#str2time-DATE-ZONE):

> `str2time` parses `DATE` and returns a unix time value, or undef upon failure.

So if you want to handle a parse error in `str2time`, you can simply check for `undef`:

```
my $parsed_time = str2time($stime);
if (!defined $parsed_time) {
    # ... handle this case
} else {
    my $dur = $etime - $parsed_time;
    ...
}
```